# How to start inbuilt activities of Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-activity

i want to Start inbuilt com.android.contacts.ExportVCardActivity of android from package com.android.contacts in my Application.

please tell me which permission required

Comment: Prashant, it'd be a good idea to learn about Intents

Answer (score 1):

you can call this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts",
                    "com.android.contacts.ExportVCardActivity"));
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Permission needed:

```
android.permission.READ_CONTACTS 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
```